# mysql failed connecting to MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I'm trying to transfer my database from Microsoft Access to MySQL (I'm using MySQL workbench). for that I need to connect MySQL to Access but I'm facing some problems. 
I'm following these guidelines: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-access.html
when testing the connection it shows this error message:

```
Unhandled exception: grt.Dict key must be string.
```

I checked the log for more information and this is what I found :

```
Starting...
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting to source...
Connecting to ...
Opening ODBC connection to DSN=northwind...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\db_msaccess_re_grt.py", line 701, in connect
    return MsAccessReverseEngineering.connect(connection, password)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\db_msaccess_re_grt.py", line 152, in connect
    con = db_driver.connect(connection, password)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\workbench\db_driver.py", line 95, in connect
    connection = library.connect(connection_string, password=password)
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 71, in run
    self.func()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\migration_source_selection.py", line 456, in task_connect
    username = self.main.plan.migrationSource.connection.parameterValues.userName
KeyError: 'grt.Dict key must be a string'
ERROR: Error during Connect to source DBMS: 'grt.Dict key must be a string'
ERROR: Exception in task 'Connect to source DBMS': KeyError('grt.Dict key must be a string',)

Failed
```

It seems that I need to make some changes in the files but I don't have any idea how to do that and I couldn't find answers to that online.

Comment: I have same issue, how did u fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Hello this is late [very]. The solution that worked for me was  making sure during adding a DSN (Data Source Name) you added your database [as in the ms access file]

See this image if my words aren't clear:

[image: See this image if my words aren't clear]

Answer (score 0):

You see this error if you're trying to migrate data from an old-format database (Access < 2010 `.mdb` file) using a newer ODBC connector. First save the file in a more recent format first (`.accdb`), and then try the migration again.